# PowerShell replace unknown 3 letter word after operator

Tags: regex, powershell

I am new to regex, can someone help me figure out how to replace unknown text while reading from a file

I am searching through a file for DEST=XXX

I dont know what XXX could be, I just know it's a 3 letter String

Here what I have so far

```
   Get-Content -path $filePath -replace 'DEST=\w{3}','DEST=MTG'
```

Comment: `(Get-Content file.txt) -replace 'DEST=\w{3}', 'DEST=MTG' | Out-File newfile.txt`

Comment: thank you I forgot | Set-Content